# How to set the scope flag in lerna exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, exec, lerna

I'm trying to run a script in lerna that would execute on all components within a specific folder.

So I'm trying to run something like

```
lerna --scope src/subfolder/subfolder exec -- npm run myScript
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: No packages found that match scope 'src/subfolder/subfolder'
```

I have tried to use different kinds of paths but none of them worked. What is the proper way of using the scope flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the scope flag should match your repo name in package.json

In your case, it seems that you should register your script folder as a package of your repo, then you can run your script in that package.